# PROC ARIMA for Multivariate analysis

Tags: sas, regression, forecasting, proc

I am trying to forecast sales for various products. I noticed that the dataset has some seasonality so I am trying to use ARIMA modeling. I have 6 products and I am trying to get SAS to forecast all 6 products at the same time. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Not in PROC ARIMA.  It only handles the univariate case.

You need to look at PROC VARMAX (Vector Autoregression Moving Average with Exongenous Variables).

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/68148/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_varmax_overview.htm

Another option would be PROC MODEL (the Swiss Army Knife of ETS).

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/68148/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_model_sect001.htm

Answer (score 0):

If the data is six univariate series with no exogenous variables (or if you want to ignore the exogenous variables and try univariate forecasts anyway) you can still use univariate models.

You could use `PROC FORECAST`.  This will not only run 6 forecasts simultaneously, but can also automatically fit various time-series models (autoregressive, exponential smoothing etc).

Or fit multiple ARIMA models you could run `PROC ARIMA` in a macro loop.

As an alternative to SAS, you could use the R [Forecast](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/forecast.pdf) package, which can do automatic model selection (including ARIMA).